# BigQuery Where Date is Less Than or Equal to 3 Days Minus Current Date

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a query to only return data where date is minus 3 days from the current date.  I've tried:

`date <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -3, 'DAY')`

But this returns `Error: Expected INTERVAL expression`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See WHERE clause in below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT i, date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-04-15', '2017-04-28')) AS date WITH OFFSET AS i
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
-- ORDER BY date
```

Btw, in case if you are still with Legacy SQL - see below example

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT *
FROM -- yourTable  
  (SELECT 1 AS id, DATE('2017-04-20') AS date),
  (SELECT 2 AS id, DATE('2017-04-21') AS date),
  (SELECT 3 AS id, DATE('2017-04-22') AS date),
  (SELECT 4 AS id, DATE('2017-04-23') AS date),
  (SELECT 5 AS id, DATE('2017-04-24') AS date),
  (SELECT 6 AS id, DATE('2017-04-25') AS date)
WHERE TIMESTAMP(date) <= DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), -3, 'DAY')
-- ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 8):

This works with a string formatted date.

`DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)) <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and seems to work.

I added this :
and DATE(TIMESTAMP(datevalue)) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)

and managed to get all records greater than last 21 days worth. Only thing I changed from @ericbrownaustin 's code was changed the 'date' in the first piece of code in the second set of parenthesis.